# wxwidgets : How can I kill a progressbar when the worker thread is done?

Tags: multithreading, progress-bar, wxwidgets

The user interface has a button Start that when clicked launches a worker thread and the thread does:

```
- starts local bluetooth radio.
- start searching for remote radios.
```

while worker thread is doing that I would like to display a progress bar. Here is my plan:

```
void MyFrame::OnStart(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
   /* launch worker thread */
   int count = 0;
   bool bSkip = false;
   while (1)
   {
     wxProgressBar *p_pb = new wxProgressBar(...);
     count++;
     Sleep(500);
     /* update progress bar to new value */
     p_pb->update(count, wxStringEmpty, &bSkip);

     /* need a way to get out of here when the worker thread is done */
   }
}

/* custom event, fired when bluetooth is done */
void MyFrame::OnBluetoothSearchDone(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
   /* we know the thread is done because this event is fired */
   /* get data (if any) from the bluetooth module */
}
```

as you can see after I fire the worker thread the main UI thread is stuck in the progressbar loop and will never catch the event that is sent by the worker thread.

if there is a way to check for pending events then I can do that in the progressbar loop and if there is then I can breakout? OR maybe call the update method on the progressbar from an idle function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such such thing as `wxProgressBar` in wxWidgets. If you're using `wxProgressDialog` and its `Update()` method, events should be already dispatched because it calls `wxYield()` internally. If you don't, you can either do it yourself -- but make sure you understand the dangers of doing this! -- or, better, avoid entering a loop at all and just disable the elements of the UI that can't be used and use a timer to update the progress indicator.

Comment: I wrote the code in the question from memory while at work (lunch break ;) ) so yes you are right.

Comment: what I did was just fired a timer and periodically update the progress. When the thread returns I just stop the timer. works very well actually :)

Comment: can you please provide a link where it says that wxprogressdialog uses wxyeild??

Comment: so basically I can override the YeildFor() method and do my update there but I should watch out for the event posted by the worker thread.

Comment: You could override `YieldFor()` but this is very rarely necessary. Just handle the events as usual instead.